# Фиксирование при скроле

Tags: html, css

Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство `position:fixed` у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо

```css
.header{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
margin: 0 25px 15px 25px;
}

.logo_and_menu{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo_and_menu nav div{
padding: 5px;
height: 45px;
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
border-radius: 5px'
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
<div class="logo_and_menu">
<img src="/assets/media/Canva.png">
<nav>
  <div><a>Home</a></div>
  <div><a>Design</a></div>
  <div><a>Templates</a></div>
  <div><a>Features</a></div>
  <div><a>Learn</a></div>
  <div><a>Plans</a></div>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 8px 8px;
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  padding-top: 8px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Header</header>
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
  <p>Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть блок header с контентом. Я хочу, чтобы он оставался на месте, а контент при скролившемся под него. Однако, когда я задаю свойство position:fixed у меня все сносится. Как исправить? Спасибо
</main>
```